# CUDA triple loop

Tags: c, for-loop, cuda

I am pretty new to CUDA and I'm very struggling with converting a C code to CUDA C, it builds successfully but it keeps crashing. Triple loop function is wrong for sure and I have no idea what should I change.

Function call:

```
for (z=0;z<=max;z++)    
    {
    correlationsum=coefficient(x, n, dim, z);
    printf("result for epsilon %d returns %d\n", z, correlation_sum);
    }
```

---

Function

```
long coefficient(int vctr[40000], long numberofpoints, int coefficientrow, int epsilon)
{
long i, j, k, sum, numberofpairs;
long sq_epsilon;
sq_epsilon=epsilon*epsilon;
numberofpairs=0;
for (i=1;i<=numberofpoints-coefficientrow;i++)
    {
    sum=0;
    for (j=i+1;j<=numberofpoints+1-coefficientrow;j++)
        {
        for (k=0;k<coefficientrow;k++)
            {
            sum=sum+(vctr[i+k]-vctr[j+k])*(vctr[i+k]-vctr[j+k]);                
            }
        if(sum<sq_epsilon)  
            {
            numberofpairs++;
            sum=0;
            }
        }
    }
return (numberofpairs);
}
```

---

I have problems limiting the function in GPU part, so it doesn't go out of bounds (e.g. k is less than coefficientrow above). I saw that it is possible to assign block/threadids and use if function. I have tried it but in triple for loop it is kinda... strange.

Here is almost full code.

```
    #define THREADS 1024
__global__ void coefficient(int *vctr, int numberofpoints, int coefficient_row, int epsilon, int *numbofpairs){
        int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
        int j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
        int k = blockIdx.z * blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;
        int sum;
        numbofpairs = 0;
        int sq_epsilon = epsilon*epsilon;


        if (i <= numberofpoints - coefficient_row)
        {
            sum = 0;
            if (j <= numberofpoints + 1 - coefficient_row)
            {
                if (k < coefficient_row)
                    sum = sum + (vctr[i + k] - vctr[j + k])*(vctr[i + k] - vctr[j + k]);
                if (sum < sq_epsilon){
                    numbofpairs++;
                    sum = 0;
    }}}}    

int main()
{
int n, dim, max, z;
int *d_n, *d_dim, *d_z, *d_x, *d_numbofpairs;
int x[40000], correlation_sum = 0;
    n=10;  
    max=10;
    dim=3;  

    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_n, sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_dim, sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_z, sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_x, sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_numbofpairs, sizeof(int));

    cudaMemcpy(d_n, &n, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_dim, &dim, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_x, &x, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    for (z = 0; z <= max; z++)
    {
        cudaMemcpy(d_z, &z, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        coefficient << <1, THREADS >> >(d_x, *d_n, *d_dim, *d_z, d_numbofpairs);
        cudaMemcpy(&correlation_sum, d_numbofpairs, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        printf("result for epsilon %d returns %d\n", z, correlation_sum);
    }
    cudaFree(d_n);
    cudaFree(d_dim);
    cudaFree(d_z);
    cudaFree(d_x);
    cudaFree(d_numbofpairs);
    return 0;
}
```

I would like some help or tips what to change, what is wrong and why it keeps crashing so I could fix it. Thank you!

EDIT: I completed some parts, sorry my bad. As for threads and blocks, I am very confused, GPU shows 1024 threads per block, and I'm not sure whether it's it or not.

Comment: You should always [check the CUDA return values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api/14038590#14038590). Also, you should provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Although you have shown some efforts in your work and this question, there are missing values in your code. We don't know the limit of your loop, neither the number of threads, if there is another memory allocation that could crash the entirely program... You should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As you are starting with CUDA, add proper CUDA error checking to your code. Do not be discouraged if you see negative votes. Improve you question to get good and high quality answers.

Comment: Thank you guys, I have edited my post and provided a MCVE (if i got it right, still learning english).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the "crash" is a seg fault.  A seg fault is a problem in *host* code, not kernel code (although it could be in your usage of the CUDA API).

Your code has a variety of problems.

1. This might cause trouble:

   ```
   int x[40000]
   ```

   this creates a large stack-based allocation.  Instead I suggest doing a dynamic allocation:

   ```
   int *x = (int *)malloc(40000*sizeof(int));
   ```

   dynamic allocations have much higher size limits.
2. It's fairly clear from your kernel usage that you intend to use the whole `x` vector.  Therefore, this allocation on the device for `d_x` is not correct:

   ```
   cudaMalloc((void **)&d_x, sizeof(int));
   ```

   we need the same size allocation on the device as what we have on the host:

   ```
   cudaMalloc((void **)&d_x, 40000*sizeof(int));
   ```
3. Corresponding to 2, you probably would want to copy the entire `x` vector to the device (it's not really clear since your code doesn't show the initialization of `x`), *and* you have incorrectly taken the address of `x` here, but `x` is *already* a pointer:

   ```
   cudaMemcpy(d_x, &x, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
   ```

   so we want something like this instead:

   ```
   cudaMemcpy(d_x, x, 40000*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
   ```
4. Your other kernel parameters appear to be scalar parameters.  You're mostly handling those incorrectly as well:

   ```
   __global__ void coefficient(int *vctr, int numberofpoints, int coefficient_row, int epsilon, int *numbofpairs){
   ```

   for a parameter like `numberofpoints` specified as above (one-way pass to function), we simply *pass by value* the host quantity we want when calling the kernel, just like we would with an ordinary C function.  So this kernel invocation is not correct (even though it appears to compile):

   ```
   coefficient << <1, THREADS >> >(d_x, *d_n, *d_dim, *d_z, d_numbofpairs);
   ```

   instead we want to pass just the host variables, by value:

   ```
   coefficient << <1, THREADS >> >(d_x, n, dim, z, d_numbofpairs);
   ```

   since `d_numbofpairs` is going both ways, your usage is correct there.
5. I would also recommend adding [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) to your code.

Here is a fully worked example with the above errors fixed.  I think the results are bogus of course because the input data (e.g. `x`) is not initialized.

```
$ cat t724.cu
#include <stdio.h>

#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)


#define THREADS 1024

__global__ void coefficient(int *vctr, int numberofpoints, int coefficient_row, int epsilon, int *numbofpairs){
        int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
        int j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
        int k = blockIdx.z * blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;
        int sum;
        numbofpairs = 0;
        int sq_epsilon = epsilon*epsilon;


        if (i <= numberofpoints - coefficient_row)
        {
            sum = 0;
            if (j <= numberofpoints + 1 - coefficient_row)
            {
                if (k < coefficient_row)
                    sum = sum + (vctr[i + k] - vctr[j + k])*(vctr[i + k] - vctr[j + k]);
                if (sum < sq_epsilon){
                    numbofpairs++;
                    sum = 0;
    }}}}

int main()
{
  int n, dim, max, z;
  int  *d_x, *d_numbofpairs;
  int correlation_sum = 0;
  int *x = (int *)malloc(40000*sizeof(int));
  if (x == NULL) {printf("malloc fail\n"); return -1;}
    n=10;
    max=10;
    dim=3;

    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_x, sizeof(int));
    cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc 1 fail");
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_numbofpairs, sizeof(int));
    cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc 2 fail");
    cudaMemcpy(d_x, x, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy 1 fail");

    for (z = 0; z <= max; z++)
    {
        coefficient << <1, THREADS >> >(d_x, n, dim, z, d_numbofpairs);
        cudaMemcpy(&correlation_sum, d_numbofpairs, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy 2/kernel fail");
        printf("result for epsilon %d returns %d\n", z, correlation_sum);
    }
    cudaFree(d_x);
    cudaFree(d_numbofpairs);
    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t724 t724.cu
$ ./t724
result for epsilon 0 returns 3
result for epsilon 1 returns 3
result for epsilon 2 returns 3
result for epsilon 3 returns 3
result for epsilon 4 returns 3
result for epsilon 5 returns 3
result for epsilon 6 returns 3
result for epsilon 7 returns 3
result for epsilon 8 returns 3
result for epsilon 9 returns 3
result for epsilon 10 returns 3
$
```

Note that I didn't make any changes to your kernel code.

Comment: Sorry for making it unclear. _x_ is an array of numbers (read from file) up to 40000. So I need to pass whole array to device, how will the kernel call change?

Comment: the kernel call doesn't need to change at all.  The `x` vector, via `d_x`, is passed in it's entirety (all 40000 elements) to the kernel, in my code.

Comment: Alright got it. The last thing is kernel itself - _j,j_ and _k_. Values of _j_ and _k_ do not look like changing at all, I guess _blockId.x/y/z*blockDim.x/y/z+threadIdx.x/y/z_ is not the right solution?

Comment: Yes, you are launching a one-dimensional grid, and one-dimensional threadblock, so `j` and `k` will always be 1.  Since I have no idea what you are trying to compute in the kernel, I can't really say what makes sense.  The crashing problem is fixed, right?  If you have new questions I suggest asking new questions on SO.